# finding relation in two classes, composition in c++

Tags: c++, composition

if I can use getters to access the private data of one class to another class then why should I use composition.

I have one more question
I have created two classes, and each class has an object array, we are told to find relation between two classes so I declared class A as private member of class B, but i am not able to access the private members of class A in class B, how do I do that?
,,,

```
// Online C++ compiler to run C++ program online
#include <iostream>
class A
{
    int a;
    public:
    A(int s=0)
    {
        a=s;
    }
    
int get_details()
    {
        return a;
    }
};
class B
{
    int b;
    A *temp;
    public:
    B(int k=0)
    {
        b=k;
    }
   
    void show(A *aa)
    {    temp=aa;
        std::cout<<"hello"<<b<<aa->get_details();
    }
    
};
int main() {
    // Write C++ code here
    std::cout << "Hello world!";
     A *a=new A(10);
     B *b=new B(20);
     
     b->show(a);
    return 0;
}
```

,,,

Comment: ironically the second part of the question explains why the first has a false premise. Composition and encapsulation are orthogonal. Whether you use getters and setters is no reason for or against composition.

Comment: // Online C++ compiler to run C++ program online
#include <iostream>
class A
{
    int a;
    public:
    A(int s=0)
    {
        a=s;
    }
    
int get_details()
    {
        return a;
    }
};
class B
{
    int b;
    A *temp;
    public:
    B(int k=0)
    {
        b=k;
    }
   
    void show(A *aa)
    {    temp=aa;
        std::cout<<"hello"<<b<<aa->get_details();
    }
    
};
int main() {
    // Write C++ code here
    std::cout << "Hello world!";
     A *a=new A(10);
     B *b=new B(20);
     
     b->show(a);
    return 0;
}

Comment: here if i can pass second first class under second class as a parameter, then why there is way of declaring first class private in second part. A *temp.

Comment: please include a [mcve] of your code in the question. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67382900/edit) the question. Code in comments is not readable

Comment: yeah i have edited code